# Keep Title and Description always

Tags: customization, title, wp-title

I want to keep the title and description of wordpress blog like this: Title | Description (showed in a tab of navigator). And I don't want to change his name while I am surfing the site.

I think that changing a little header.php could be solution but is bad option change a file directly. Only I know that title is here:

Any idea or advice?

Comment: You can use a child theme where you clone the header.php, and edit it as you want, in this case the tag <title>. It would be a safe solution, and useful for future changes.

Comment: Or you could filter the title and description from your child themes functions file.

Comment: Which option is better for quick of site load? Child theme?

Comment: If you are only concerned with the item in your navigation menu, just go to Appearance > Menu in your admin panel and change the Navigation Label to match your site's title and description.

Comment: I just realized "navigator" in this question is referring to the browser and this question is asking about filtering how the title is displayed in the [Title Bar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_bar). Disregard my previous suggestion. ^_^

Comment: Sorry for my bad knowledge of English :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any properly coded theme the title should be completely generated with [`wp_title()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_title/) and easily filterable to specific string (in `functions.php` or otherwise):

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', function () {
    return get_bloginfo( 'name' ) . ' | ' . get_bloginfo( 'description' );
} );
```

Comment: Good answer, although you should metion that anonymous functions are available only in some versions of php..

Comment: @DanielGarciaSanchez no. PHP 5.2 was last version without closures and it had been unsupported for more than three years now. If someone chooses to use it — it's their problem, not everyone's problem. :)

Comment: Aha, then it's perfect :-) It was only a tip

Comment: Neil: One advantage of this method is that you can use it in a plugin instead of a theme file. This way you can change themes and it will still be applied. [Writing a Plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin)

Comment: Thanks @Rarst and @RyanLoremIpsum for your help. Finally I changed a little because it appears 'Title | Title | Description'. I only deleted the blog info name:
`add_filter( 'wp_title', function () {
    return get_bloginfo( 'description' );
} );`
And all works fine! :)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to filtering, this method would be used to replace `<title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>` in your header.php file (ideally in a child theme).

`bloginfo('name','description');` will display the site title and description.

From [Function Reference/bloginfo](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo)

> - 'name' - Displays the "Site Title" set in Settings > General. This    data is retrieved from the "blogname" record in the wp_options table.
> - 'description' - Displays the "Tagline" set in Settings > General.    This data is retrieved from the "blogdescription" record in the
>     wp_options table.

Here's an example given for displaying title and description in the title section of your header.php:
`<title><?php bloginfo('name','description'); ?></title>`